# Creating a counter Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to make a counter out of the following code:

```
contador([], 0,[]).
contador([via(A,_,_)|R], Tot,Regiao):-
   cidade(A,_,_,Reg1),Reg1==Regiao,
   Tr is Tot + 1,
   contador(R,Tr,Regiao).
```

Given my list's format and cidade:

```
L=[via(porto,lisboa,_),via(braga,faro,_),via(guimaraes,santarem,_)]

cidade(lisboa,_,_,A)
```

Why isn't it working?

```
cidade(porto,portugal,40,litoral).
cidade(braga,portugal,350,interior).
cidade(guimares,portugal,40,litoral).
cidade(alverca,portugal,30,valedotejo).
cidade(santarem,portugal,25,valedotejo).
cidade(faro,portugal,20,litoral).
cidade(sevilha,espanha,60,interior).
```

With this list:

```
A = [via(porto, braga, 5), via(braga, guimaraes, 9), via(guimaraes, alverca, 7), via(alverca, faro, 10)] ;
```

I'm trying to do the following:

```
?-contador(A,Tot,litoral).
false.
```

My objective is to count the cities that have `A(cidades(_,_,_,A))` as a parameter.

Comment: Show the full code including database facts and the query you are trying to run.

Comment: What happens if `Regiao` and `Reg1` are different?

Comment: It should skip that member of the list,not incrementing Tot and go to the next one

Comment: That's not what you described: You simply stated that they have to be identical. So if they are not your program fails. My advice would be either to study `setof/3` first, or at least use `library(clpfd)` for the integers (instead of the incorrect use of `(is)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in the code you presented.

1)

First, a remark, in Prolog, "=" is not an assignment like in C/C++ and other imperative languages. That means you can not type:

```
A=[...].
contador(...).
```

but use a single query:

```
 A=[...],contador(...).
```

2)

These two statements are possibly an error:

```
contador([], 0,[]).
contador([via(A,_,_)|R], Tot,Regiao):-...
```

because third argument is in the first one a list, and is not in the second.

3)

Finally, what you call a "contador/counter" ( and that is, probably, better called an "accumulator" ) is not correctly "finished". When the original list is exhausted, the statement:

```
contador([], 0,[]).
```

is applied, but this statement request counter equal to cero. Probably, it will be better something like:

```
contador([], R, _) :- ... /* do something with R */
```

4)

These two statements:

```
cidade(A,_,_,Reg1),Reg1==Regiao,
```

can be unified in a single one:

```
cidade(A,_,_,Regiao),
```

5) 
In general, try to skip "is" operator. By example, replace:

```
Tr is Tot + 1,
```

with:

```
succ(Tot,Tr),
```

6)

If statement:

```
cidade(A,_,_,Reg1),Reg1==Regiao,
```

fails, you have not an alternative rule.

Comment: Using it this way:
`contador([],0,_).
contador([via(A,_,_)|R], Tot,Regiao):-
 cidade(A,_,_,Regiao),
 succ(Tot,Tr),
 contador(R,Tr,Regiao).
`
When reaching succ(Tot,Tr) it says arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.

Comment: In the query, you must pass an intiial counter equal to "0".